# Use a custom field variable as a shortcode argument value in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, barcode, shortcode

In Woocommerce, I am using [YITH WooCommerce Barcodes and QR Codes](https://yithemes.com/themes/plugins/yith-woocommerce-barcodes-and-qr-codes/) plugin and I would like to use a custom field as a value for an argument in this shortcode. Here is the [related documentation](https://docs.yithemes.com/yith-woocommerce-barcodes/how-to-use-the-plugin/shortcodes/).

That is what I would like `(where`CUSTOMFILEDVALUE`is the value of the custom field)`:

```
[yith_render_barcode value="CUSTOMFILEDVALUE" protocol="CODE39"]
```

Is it possible to include a custom field value in this kind of short code? How this can be done?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this in the backend content editor or in a template?

Comment: in HTML EDITOR INSIDE A PLUG IN

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can embed an existing Shortcode inside a custom Shortcode function. The following code is an example based on other similar functional answers.

In this code I get the post id of the pages, posts or custom posts. You can specify a post ID using the shortcode id argument as in the original shortcode.

The code:

```
function custom_yith_render_barcode( $atts ) {
    // Shortcode attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '0', // Product ID
        'hide_if_empty' => '1',
        'value' => '',
        'protocol' => 'EAN8',
    ), $atts, 'render_barcode' );

    global $post;

    if( '0' === $atts['id'] && $post && is_object($post) )
        $id = $post->ID;
    elseif( $atts['id'] > 0 )
        $id = $atts['id'];

    $hide     = $atts['hide_if_empty'];
    $value    = get_post_meta( $id, $atts['value'], true ) ? get_post_meta( $id, $atts['value'], true ) : $atts['value'];
    $protocol = $atts['protocol'];

    return do_shortcode( "[yith_render_barcode id='$id' hide_if_empty='$hide' value='$value' protocol='$protocol']" );
}
add_shortcode('render_barcode', 'custom_yith_render_barcode');
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

---

**USAGE** -

Below the `meta_key` has to be replaced with the **meta key** of your custom field. All other YITH Shortcode arguments are unchanged and available. Only `value` argument is used to pass the custom field **meta key**, allowing to get the custom field value in embedded YITH shortcode.

1) In the Wordpress page or post editor:

```
[render_barcode value="meta_key" protocol="CODE39"]
```

2) In PHP code:

```
echo do_shortcode( "[render_barcode value='meta_key' protocol='CODE39']" );
```